# How to put css class in to html:select element in jsp

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, struts

I want to CSS only way to style a html dropdown in a JSP

```
<html:select name="complaintsForm" class="width_4" property="product">
     <option value="">- Please Select -</option>
     <html:options name="complaintsForm" property="productList" />
</html:select>
```

Comment: But, class is already there.

Comment: yes, thats the problem, i put class there, but it didnt render in browser, I'm asking how to solve that?

Comment: Not sure about this. Try wrapping a div like `<div class="selectBox"><html:select></html:select></div>`. then give your css properties to this class like : `.selectBox select { /*color: red*/}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. It is working fine for me.

```
<select name="complaintsForm" class="width_4" property="product">
     <option value="">- Please Select -</option>
     <html:options name="complaintsForm" property="productList" />
</select>
```

Or you can use [styleClass](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-html.html#select) attribute instead of class.

Comment: this also work for me, but i wnat put like <html:select></html:select> insted <select></select> because this is a jsp page and  i'm using struts tag element also

Comment: Then use styleClass attribute instead of class.